# Definition of server-class machine changed recently?

Tags: java, jvm

Has Oracle's definition of a server-class machine changed between releases 5.0, 6 and 7 of the JVM?

The latest specification I can find is [for 5.0](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc5.0/ergo5.html), which defines a server-class machine as:

- 2 or more physical processors
- 2 or more Gbytes of physical memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the link for the java 7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html