# What's the default JVM heap size of Java application launched by eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

If I don't set -Xmx of the Java application in eclipse. Eclipse will launch it with a default heap size which is related to the physical memory. I want to know how to compute this default value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the default maximum heap size for Sun's JVM from Java SE 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915276/what-is-the-default-maximum-heap-size-for-suns-jvm-from-java-se-6)

Comment: @BrendanLong. Thanks, "Smaller than 1/4th of the physical memory" is correct. That's really a duplicated question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MemoryMXBean to get JVM init and max memory and RuntimeMXBean to get JVM arguments.