# JUnit heap space for Eclipse in Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

How do you find out the default max heap space allowed by JUnit tests in Eclipse?
- I am using Ubuntu 14.04.
- I don't have any "Run Configuration" override

Comment: Here is one post you can Find Java Heap size not the Junit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915276/what-is-the-default-maximum-heap-size-for-suns-jvm-from-java-se-6

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse IDE Junit tests are run in a different vm.So go here ..Run configuration under `JUnit (Run>Run configuration>JUnit)` , check if any configuration exist if not add a `New` .Within the arguments tab set VM arguments to  `-Xms64m -Xmx256m`  or higher if needs be.

Here are a very good tool for Junit called [junitlaunchfixer](https://github.com/joeygibson/junitlaunchfixer)

> This plugin will automatically add a user-specified max heap setting
>   to all new JUnit launchers. It also supports one-time scanning and
>   updating of existing launchers.

Comment: No actually I was asking how can I know what is the default heap size, if no heap size is provided in configuration.